# Apache Service detected with wrong path(xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have xampp on my C Drive and it was deleted from my computer, i tried to install it again on the C drive but i failed, so i ended up installing it on my E drive.

And when i open it it gives me this error messages.

```
2:52:51 AM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
2:52:51 AM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
2:52:51 AM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
2:52:51 AM  [Apache]    Found Path: "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
2:52:51 AM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "e:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Found Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Expected Path: e:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=e:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql"!
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:52:51 AM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but if I was in your situation I would listen to what te log says..
1- Easy but pain in the ass for further configuration: Change the port in your E: configurations files of mysql etc...

2- Try to delete the path that your log is seeing for the older installation also check if you can modify the mysql service that is running on port 3306 or delete that service too (it should be re-configured) the next time you'll start XAMPP. Don't forget to restart your php and mysql if you try this..

3- Easiest: delete/uninstall both of your XAMP path location and every mysql service that might run and do a complete instalatio again for XAMPP...

ps: Sorry for the format of that text I never comment on stackoverflow my bad ;)